# Data gateway instance not found on Azure

Tags: database, azure, networking, azure-logic-apps, gateway

I have installed OPDG using below document (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install). I could able to successfully install on my machine , But when I tried to create the gateway connection on Azure I couldn't find the instance. Here I have attached the screenshot. Appreciate if you can support.

Note : I am using the same email address to install and Azure Access and both region are same

[image]

Comment: You could check the Q2 in the troubleshooting https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#troubleshooting also, Check the Important considerations in Prerequisites, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-gateway-install#prerequisites

Comment: Thanks @NancyXiong. I have already checked both. As mentioned on that link,  I have reviewed GW in all my sub and also my PC is satisfying the requirements

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure what your issue is but I would try troubleshooting it further with the help of Powershell, I had a similar issue where I could not install a new gateway. The issue for me was that a gateway was previously installed on the same machine. By using the PowerShell OnPremisesDataGatewayMgmt module I could remove what seemed to block me.

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/OnPremisesDataGatewayMgmt/1.0.0-beta1

Comment: Thanks @AdAstra for the reply. I will check and let u know

Comment: AdAstra, I have tried to install, but I couldn't install successfully. I think now this module has deprecated. Even they have mentioned on this doc. "The owner has unlisted this package. This could mean that the module is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore."

Comment: Oh, what a shame.. You can try with a manual install, download the powershell nuget package from the page. Otherwise if that does not work you could even try with just importing the psm file as it is in plain text also on the powershellgallery page. Use the functions you would need. I hope that help!